# how to make that a sidebar take all the height of our web page?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sass, angular-material

here is my current sidebar:

[image: sidebar]

I would like that it always take all the height, how to do please?

I already tested height: 100% but it doesn't work here is my csss code:

```
#sidebar {
    /* don't forget to add all the previously mentioned styles here too */
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    /*background: #7386D5; */
    background-color: rgb(31, 40, 55);
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    float: left;
    height : 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`height: 100%` will make it take 100% of the container's height. Try using `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` to make it take 100% of the screen's height:

```
#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 250px;
}
```